# How to configure Jenkins Jobs to use Maven repositories and clean

Tags: git, maven, jenkins

We have 50+ Jenkins jobs with concurrent builds enabled. Because they can install different versions of the same snapshot (building different feature branches), using one Maven repository for all jobs is not an option. For now, we use one maven repo for each job workspace.
But in order to not download the dependencies every time, we don’t clean the workspace anymore, which results in other issues. We would like to be able to clean the workspace.
We see several options:

1. Have a near cache on each Jenkins node, in order to be able to fast reconstruct the maven repository inside the workspace after cleanup.
2. Have one maven repo per workspace, but outside the workspaces. Disadvantage: disk space – 50+ repos with mostly the same artifacts. We already have this issue with the current setup.
3. Write a maven extension to separate releases from snapshots into two different maven repos.
4. Manually clean the workspace before checkout. Disadvantage: we would checkout the project twice – once by Jenkins, because the Jenkinsfile is stored with the project, and once after cleanup.
5. Use git clean and find a solution to skip the maven repo folder (-x?)

What do you recommend?